# How to cancel CountDown Timer when home button is pressed?

Tags: java, android

In my game I have a countdown timer, and when I press home button and leave the game, the timer goes on and when it hits 0 my game pops back on, cause the time is up, and I get some info screen for time up. How to kill the timer at least when I hit the home button? I tried with this but it didn't work:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        {
            timer.cancel();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Try to log if the onKeyDown event works first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `Activity onUserLeaveHint()`

Method description from javadoc:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key

---

Above solution works for HOME button just fine. However, consider overriding `onPause()` method of your `Activity` and cancel timer there. This way you will cancel timer whenever your game is paused. Unless you treat HOME as a special case, then follow my first part of the answer.